# How to import products,customers,product prices automatically in Magento?

Tags: magento, import, cron, jobs, job-scheduling

I am interested to know how to **import** products, customers, Prices etc. without manually do importing i.e. **automatically in Magento**?

From the forum I get some idea as we can run **CRON job scheduling technique** for the same? So how exactly it works?

Or is there any **Magento extension** available for the same?
Can I import products from external system say Oracle ERP in Magento using cron jobs?

My requirement is that, I have access to both Oracle & Mysql Database through PHP & now we need to take product prices, customer info. etc. from **Oracle to Magento** that to **automatically**(Right now thinking of Cron Job technique)...So how can I import product prices from Oracle database into Magento database **AUTOMATICALLY**...
plz give me some suggestion.
Anyone tried this before...

waiting for Responses..

---

Can we use **Magmi** for Magento EE 1.10.0.1 edition as during configuring Magmi, it's asking for Magento version which only provide CE versions...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of Magento extensions that will help you here. One of which is [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page), however I haven't had any experience with this.

I use the [AMartinez_CustomImportExport](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/amartinez-customimportexport.html) extension for this purpose. The extension has a script that you can execute from the command line, so you can therefore add it to your system crontab like below (replacing `MAGENTO_ROOT` with the absolute path to where you have Magento installed).

`0 0 * * *  php MAGENTO_ROOT/amartinez_customimportexport.php -- -all -import var/customimportexport/test_single_row_style.csv`

This would execute an import at 00:00 everyday, refreshing all caches and reindexing.

See the [forum thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/227005/) for this extension for more information.

Comment: Hi Jamie, Can we able to import products from Oracle ERP using this extension?  If so, how exactly?